# Android make continues scrolling text within single view in repeat mode

Tags: android

I am trying to implement ticker board where you can see all ticker in scrolling mode check below image,

[image]

now I want continue scrolling for example

**in @user5** after some space and start again with this same value no blank area like in init space

I want like this

```
scrolling text from one user 3 hours @user3   <some space>     scrolling text from...
```

sorry for bad english

here is my code

```
            View view = parent_layout.getChildAt(index);
        // measures the unconstrained size of the view
        // before it is drawn in the layout
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,
                View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        // takes the unconstrained width of the view
        float width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        float height = view.getMeasuredHeight();

        // gets the screen width

        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) width,
                (int)height));

        Log.e("contact details","width and screenwidth are" + width + "/"
                + screenWidth + "///" + view.getMeasuredWidth());

        // performs the calculation
        toXDelta = width - (screenWidth - 0);

        // sets toXDelta to -300 if the text width is smaller that the
        // screen size
        if (toXDelta < 0) {
            toXDelta = 0 - screenWidth;// -300;
        } else {
            toXDelta = 0 - screenWidth - toXDelta;// -300 - toXDelta;
        }
//          tickerList.add(view);
//          animList.add(mAnimation);
         // Animation parameters
            mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(screenWidth,
                    toXDelta, 0, 0);
            mAnimation.setDuration(15000);
//          mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            view.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is just create double of string means appending current string with itself if the length is lower then screen width and using marquee feature in Textview.

```
private float screenWidth;

onCreate(){
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Point outSize = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(outSize);
    screenWidth = outSize.x;
    StringBuilder ticker = new StringBuilder("This is my String");

    do{
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(ticker.toString()));
        int w = ticker.length();
        if(screenWidth>w){
            ticker.append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            ticker.append(tickerList.get(index));
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(ticker.toString()));
        }else
            break;
    }while(true);
}
```

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1">

</TextView>
```